# How can I create an AUTO_INCREMENT column in a table that already exists and has data?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I want to create a column that will auto increment when a new row is inserted. 
The table has already data and this data does not need to receive this index, or it can be NULL. I just want to start to increment since now.

It looks simple, but I run in Workbench this:

```
ALTER TABLE `serra`.`acionamento` 
ADD COLUMN `indice` INT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT AFTER `date_insercao`
```

... and it says

> Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key

This column really needs to be a primary key?

Comment: 'To use the AUTO_INCREMENT mechanism with an InnoDB table, an AUTO_INCREMENT column must be defined as part of an index such that it is possible to perform the equivalent of an indexed SELECT MAX(ai_col) lookup on the table to obtain the maximum column value. Typically, this is achieved by making the column the first column of some table index.' - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html so not necessarily the primary key but no its' all all or nothing you cannot start from a point in time..

Comment: You cannot use the 'autoincrement' mechanism for this. imo, you are going to have to implement it yourself with separate columns on the table and a separate table of 'sequences / date' and triggers. Please do not try playing / changing with the primary key 'autoincrement' column. That will end in tears. ;-/

Comment: Thanks for the comments, they had clarified my doubts!

Comment: Your idea is not bad. Unfortunately MySQL does not allow multiple identity columns on a table, unlike PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution I was looking for...

I was missing an UNIQUE configuration...

```sql
ALTER TABLE `serra`.`acionamento` 
ADD COLUMN `indice` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT AFTER `column`,
ADD UNIQUE INDEX `indice_UNIQUE` (`indice` ASC);
```

Thanks for the comments